# Function persists once called, even after going through if statement test

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have multiple spans inside of a div. We want spans to revert to the original layout when user clicks white space. This is the code:

```
var whiteSpace = function (){

  $(function(){
    $('div').on('click',function(e) {
      if (e.target !== this)
        return;
      originalL();
    });
  });
};
```

The problem is we have two modes, work mode and set mode, and we want this to only work in the work mode. We change modes with keypress,

```
$(document).on("keypress", function (e){
  if(e.which === 83) {
    alert('"Shift + s" was pressed.  Start Setup Mode.');
    state = "false";
    dragResize();
   var whiteSpaceDisable = function (){
      $(function(){
        $('div').off('click',function(e) {
          if (e.target !== this)
            return;
          originalL();
        });
      });
    };
    whiteSpaceDisable();
  }

  if(e.which === 87) {
    alert('"Shift + w" was pressed.  Start Work Mode.');
    state = "true";
    dragDropWidget ();
    dragResizeDisable();
   whiteSpace = function (){

      $(function(){  
        $('div').on('click',function(e) {
          if (e.target !== this)
            return;
          originalL();
        });
      });
    };
    whiteSpace();
  }
});
```

When user tries to go to the set mode from the work mode first time, it works. However, when user tries to the same thing second time, it doesn't work. WhiteSpace function persists.
How can we turn this function off in the set mode? By the way, page reload is not an option.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In your keypress handler, replace:

```
var whiteSpace = ...
```

with:

```
whiteSpace = ...
```

Right now you're just assigning the other function to a *new* `whiteSpace` variable that is scoped to that keypress handler function. If you want to override the previously defined `whiteSpace` variable, you need to make sure you're actually assigning to that same variable reference, not creating a new one.

Comment: Sorry for that. It still does not work. But thank you for responding!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by placing 'if conditional' inside the originalL function, so it will evaluate before firing.  this was the problem.
We just made a 'workMode' variable that can be set to whatever value we need through keypress function.
  Here's the code that fixed it:

```
var workMode = "off";
function originalL() {
if (workMode === "on"){
small1O();
small2O();
smalllongO();
smallwideO();
}
};
```

and at bottom of page, at the keystroke listeners, putting this:

```
$(document).on("keypress", function (e) {

if (e.which === 83) {

    alert('"Shift + s" was pressed.  Start Setup Mode.');
    workMode = "off";
    dragResize();
    originalL();
}
;
if (e.which === 87) {

    alert('"Shift + w" was pressed.  Start Work Mode.');
    workMode = "on";
    smalllongExpand();
    originalL();
    dragResizeDisable();
}
```